# Using span to prove subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra

$W = \begin{pmatrix}
    a \\
    -a \\
   2a
\end{pmatrix} , a \ \in \mathbb{R}$

I know I can prove this a subspace in $ \mathbb{R}^3 $easily by checking closure under addition and closure under scalar multiplication. However, can I say that $W = a\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
-1\\
2\\ \end{pmatrix}$ and thus $W = \mathrm{span}\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
-1\\
2\\ \end{pmatrix}$. And if W is in the span ${(v_1...v_k)}$ then it is a subspace in $\mathbb{R}^3 $ ?

Comment: What are the $v_1,\cdots ,v_k$? Also, spans are subspaces by definition.

Comment: Ignoring the  v's, does the argument I provided make sense?

Comment: But how do you know that the span of a set of vectors is a vector space in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You defined the set:
$$W = \left\{ a \cdot \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ -1 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix} \: | \: a \in \mathbb{R}  \right\}$$
Which is by definition the span of $(1,-1,2)$. Yes, it is a subspace, as you said.